# Sockets multiplexing in Elixir

Tags: elixir

How to do multiplexing sockets in Elixir? I need connect to core banking, but it only accepts just one tcp connection and my app received many concurrent connections. Any suggestions?

Comment: Spin up one process per socket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd wrap the whole socket handling in a GenServer, which will then act as a gateway and only process one message at a time. For example:

```
defmodule Client do
  use GenServer
  @name __MODULE__

  # API

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, [name: @name])
  end

  def command(data) do
    GenServer.call(@name, {:command, data})
  end

  # GenServer implementation

  def init(:ok) do
    :gen_tcp.connect('localhost', 9999, [active: false, packet: :line])
  end

  def handle_call({:command, data}, _from, socket) do
    :gen_tcp.send(socket, data <> "\n")
    {:ok, result} = :gen_tcp.recv(socket, 0)
    {:reply, result, socket}
  end
end
```

Then you can send many commands to the API client, but it will only process one message at a time. For example if you send 10 messages at the same time, these will get sent over the socket one after another all using a single TCP connection.

```
Client.start_link

tasks = for x <- 1..10 do
  Task.async fn ->
    IO.puts Client.command("Hello world #{x}!")
  end
end

for task <- tasks do
  Task.await(task)
end
```

You can test this locally by creating a simple echo server with `socat`:

```
socat -v tcp-l:9999,reuseaddr,fork exec:cat
```

Comment: "Spin up one process per socket." but you said it a lot better than I did  :-P

Comment: that's a great answer, but following your example , if sending 10 requests , the same the need to send one after another , and receive server responses not necessarily in the same order , ie can receive three glued answers , and I have to segment reading the first 2 bytes message , which indicates the length I of the response

Comment: Ok so you want to be able to read/write concurrently from/to the socket? Generally that should be no problem as TCP allows this by design. How is a request matched to a response? You need a way to match them if the responses are out of order. Without these details it's hard to give a good answer.

Comment: The request is a Financial Transaction, use the standard ISO8583, and the request and respond have an id (numerical value of 6 positions) with that i nedd match the response, it's very important consider the length of response message is variable, it's  important read the first two bytes of each response. Thanks for you help

Comment: Sorry, the answer is yes, i need read/write concurrently from/to socket

Comment: I dont have much time but I will try to outline a possible approach: Instead of waiting for `recv`, you can use `handle_info` on the client, gen_tcp will send a message of the form `{:tcp, socket, data}` back to you as soon as something was received. I have set the packet mode to line, but you can adjust that to your needs. You can also switch the packet mode during operation with `:inet.setopt` so you can then move over to another mode if you need this to parse the packets. Hope this helps!

Comment: I recommend reading the following pages as well: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/task-and-gen-tcp.html, http://andrealeopardi.com/posts/handling-tcp-connections-in-elixir/, http://learnyousomeerlang.com/buckets-of-sockets, http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html

Comment: Tank's Patrick, the next monday i'll try do the implementation, and again thank's